# Null exception error when setting icon into jButton after cloning from project from Github

Tags: java, user-interface, button, github, nullpointerexception

I have a simple application that uses GUI and I have decided to put images into jButtons. When I run the program on my machine, the program runs properly but when someone else clones the program onto their computer from Github including myself, a null excetpion error occurs. The link to the Github repository is:

https://github.com/MustafaAli789/TimelineApplication

The "Maintimeline" page is the one that does not run.

For some reason, Java is returning null whenever I provide the image path even though it is correct and the image is directly in the location specified.

The code below is an example of one of the lines that would throw an error:

```
 DeleteBtn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/DeleteIconHover.png")));
```

What im confused about is that it works fine on my computer but when someone else clones it or even when I clone it, it doesn't work. Also, when you clone it, you can see the images in the GUI editor perfectly fine but when running the file, Java cant seem to find the image.

I made a file reference to one of the images and then tried .getAbsolutePath and it returns a path but when I do .exists(), Java returns false. Two things, how it can determine the path but then say it doesn't exist and secondly, the path doesnt include src.

Comment: `Java is returning null whenever I provide the image path` - You are not providing an image path. You are just providing the file name.  I don'[t know how your application is set up if your are using packages or not. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) that may help explain how using resources works. I would also get rid of the leading "/".

Comment: I now tried using the following path: "src/TimelineApplication/DeleteIconHover.png" but the nullpointer exception still occurs....

Comment: I don't know why you are using that path. The classpath is where your class files are found. So the image needs to be added to a directory that is on your classpath.

Comment: Alright, it works now, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Use that `ToolKit.getImage(getClass().getResource("/DeleteIconHover.png"));`

Comment: I'm just wondering what exactly this does differently than what I already have?

Comment: I just know that work when I make my application using image on button

Comment: Try to get the file by class File and so `getAbsolutePath`

Comment: I used getAbsolutePath to get the path of one of my images and pasted that directly into the setIcon code but it still says nullError for some reason

Comment: Try all link you can and verify before the setIcon that the file exist with `new File(<Your path>).exists()`